# SendGrid Email is replacing spaces with Question Marks

Tags: .net, sendgrid, sendgrid-api-v3, sendgrid-templates

I am using Send Grid to send Emails in .NET Core API , send grid is behaving weirdly by replacing spaces with Question marks when email lands in user inbox .

This is how my HTML looks like when I open it in debug mode at backend
[image]

But I receive email like this in my inbox.

[image]

This is only happening with my organization based outlook accounts , it works fine on @outlook and @gmail

The HTML that is being generated is same for @gmail and organization office account , problem is with browser I think

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just removed charset=UTF-8 from my html and it worked.

```
 html = html.Replace("charset=UTF-8",string.Empty);
```